# how to correct the syntax '}' (})!

Tags: wordpress, syntax, content-management-system, themes

I made a migration from localhost to hosting and when I connect I get error 500 and I can not enter admin. **PHP v.5.6**

There was a previous error in the file `<?php endwhile; ?>` and I corrected it as indicated by the log error `<?php 'endwhile'; ?>`

But the error continues at the end of the file

I added more quotes `'}'` error in the next line: parse error, unexpected `'}'(})!`

```
<?php 
        }

    } // class Carousel Widget


?>
```

I hope to correct the syntax and connect the site.

Comment: Please let user know what was the prevoius error and what you did for? And also attach error log so users can review it and get idea to give solution

Comment: question was not clear some improved as I can.